# Why the price of RAM will drop 1000 times?

Tags: ram, price

[image]

As the chat shows, the price of RAM will be much lower if fractional reserve. 
But I don't understand how this happens?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a theoretical thought experiment. RAM is not recommended for investing as it is highly speculative. The probability of this fractional reserve of RAM formula being used is very low. RAM is a very young market and is in growing pains currently.

RAM is intended to be used by dApps and the speculators are just helping finding the price.